# Monotone Class Theorem for Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, monotone-class-theorem

> Suppose $\mathcal F$ is a collection of real-valued functions on $X$ such that the constant functions are in $\mathcal F$ and $f + g$, $fg$, and $cf$ are in $\mathcal F$ whenever $f, g \in \mathcal F$ and $c \in \mathbb R$. Suppose $f \in \mathcal F$ whenever $f_n \to f$ and each $f_n \in \mathcal F$. Define the function $$\textbf1_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in A;\\ 0, & x \notin A. \end{cases}$$ Prove that $\mathcal A = \{A \subseteq X : \textbf 1_A \in \mathcal F\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I have the following result at my disposal:

**Monotone Class Theorem**: Suppose $\mathcal A_0$ is an algebra, $\mathcal A$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal A_0$, and $\mathcal M$ is the smallest monotone class containing $\mathcal A_0$. Then $\mathcal M = \mathcal A$.

**Notes**: here are some observations I've made:

1. $\emptyset \in \mathcal A$ since $\textbf 1_\emptyset = 0$ is constant and $\mathcal F$ contains all constant functions, similarly $X \in \mathcal A$.
2. If $A \in \mathcal A$, then $\textbf 1_A \in \mathcal F$; notice that $1 - \textbf 1_A = \textbf 1_{A^c} \in \mathcal F$ since finite sums are of elements in $\mathcal F$ are in $\mathcal F$, hence $A^c \in \mathcal A$.
3. Let $A_1, A_2 \in \mathcal A$, then $\textbf 1_{A_1}, \textbf 1_{A_2} \in \mathcal F$. Observe that $\textbf 1_{A_1 \cap A_2} = \textbf 1_{A_1} \cdot \textbf 1_{A_2} \in \mathcal F$. By mathematical induction if $A_1, \ldots, A_n \in \mathcal A$, then $\bigcap_{i = 1}^n A_i \in \mathcal A$.
4. Since we have finite intersections and complements, we get finite unions: $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i \in \mathcal A$.

So $\mathcal A$ is an algebra. At this point we can choose to make $\mathcal A_0 := \mathcal A$ our algebra.

The problem with showing the result directly comes down to showing if $A_i \in \mathcal A$, then $\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal A$.

I'm guessing I want to show that $\mathcal M := \mathcal A_0$ is a monotone class. Once we've done this, since $\mathcal A_0 = \mathcal M$, $\mathcal M$ is obviously the smallest monotone class containing $\mathcal A_0$. By the monotone class theorem $\mathcal M = \sigma(\mathcal A_0)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, correct? (**Question 1**)

So let's try to show that $\mathcal M$ is a monotone class.

1. Let $A_k \in \mathcal M$ with $A_k \nearrow A$. In particular, we have that $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots$ and $A := \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty A_k$. Observe that (by hypothesis), $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \textbf 1_{A_n} = \textbf 1_{\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty A_k}$$ and hence $\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty A_k \in \mathcal A$. Is this step valid? It seems obvious, but I'm not sure if I've made an assumption here that I shouldn't have (**Question 2**)
2. Let $A_k \in \mathcal M$ with $A_k \searrow A$. In particular, we have that $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \cdots$ and $A := \bigcap_{k = 1}^\infty A_k$. Observe that (by hypothesis) $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \textbf 1_{A_n} = \textbf 1_{\bigcap_{k = 1}^\infty A_k}$$ and hence $\bigcap_{k = 1}^\infty A_k \in \mathcal A$.

If the reasoning in the above two steps is valid about the limit being correct, then can I skip having to use the monotone class theorem and just observe the following? (**Question 3**)

Let $A_k \in \mathcal A$, then $\textbf 1_{A_k} \in \mathcal F$. Define $B_n = \bigcup_{k = 1}^n A_k \in \mathcal A$ since we've already established that it is an algebra and algebras have finite unions. Define $f_n = \textbf 1_{B_n}$ and notice that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \textbf 1_{B_n} = \textbf 1_{\cup_{k = 1}^\infty A_k} \in \mathcal F$ by hypothesis. Hence $\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty A_k \in \mathcal A$. Conclude by definition that $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

If my reasoning fails somewhere, I would appreciate any hints/full proofs that establish the result using the monotone class theorem, if just because I feel I lack understanding of how to use it and I think this is a good example where it's usable.

Comment: I wonder whether similar approach as in van Rooij-Schikhof, A Second Course on Real Functions. [Theorem 16.6](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA104) would be possible. The authors define Borel functions first, then they define Borel sets as the sets such that $\mathbf 1_A \in \mathscr B$. (But yo are probably more interested in continuing along the lines you have already started.)

Comment: @RobertCardona Is the convergence $f_n \to f$ is pointwise? And in the paragraph of Question 1, should the $\mathcal M$ read $\mathcal A$ instead? Note that you haven't defined $\mathcal M$ anywhere (except in the statement of the monotone convergence theorem, where $\mathcal M$ is assumed to be a monotone class so "I'm guessing that [we] have to show that $\mathcal M$ is a monotone class" still doesn't make sense).

Comment: The problem didn't specify the type of convergence, but I'm assuming pointwise everywhere. As for your other question, you're right, I need to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you did seems fine to me. For completeness's sake, here's a succinct solution:

Firstly, $\boldsymbol{1}_\varnothing = 0 \in \mathcal F \implies \varnothing \in \mathcal A$. Next for $A \in \mathcal A$, we have $\boldsymbol{1}_{A^c} = 1 - \boldsymbol{1}_{A} \in \mathcal F \implies A^c \in \mathcal A$.
And finally, suppose $(A_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of sets in $\mathcal A$. Let us consider the sequence $\left(\prod_{k=1}^n \boldsymbol{1}_{A_k}\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ of functions in $\mathcal F$. If $x \in \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_k$, then $\prod_{k=1}^n\boldsymbol{1}_{A_k}(x) = 1$ for all $n$. On the other hand if $x \notin \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_k$, then $\prod_{k=1}^n \boldsymbol{1}_{A_k}(x) = 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n \boldsymbol{1}_{A_k} = \boldsymbol{1}_{\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_k}$ pointwise, implying that $\mathcal A$ is closed under countable intersections. It follows that $\mathcal A$ is indeed a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I suppose you'd also want to say that $\textbf 1_X = 1 \in \mathcal F \implies X \in \mathcal A$, but that's as trivial as the case of the emptyset, or follows from the complement.

Comment: So in the end, I ended up not needing the monotone class theorem for sets? I thought I would end up needing it somehow, given the name of this problem: "the monotone class theorem for indicator functions".

Comment: (1) Depends on your taste in the definition of $\sigma$-algebras. By closure under complementation, $\varnothing \in \mathcal A \iff X \in \mathcal A$, so most definitions that I've seen list only one of those two conditions. You can even use "$\mathcal A$ is nonempty". (2) No need. Checking that $\mathcal A$ satisfies the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra seems to be the most straightforward path.