# Understanding answer to question showing equality of two measures on the Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

I understand that this question has been asked before, however my question is in reference to a specific answer given here.

[Proving two measures of Borel sigma-algebra are equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135884/proving-two-measures-of-borel-sigma-algebra-are-equal/1142942#comment2329163_1135918)

In particular it is the last answer (which the OP provided). Conveniently their answer has numbers so I when I am referring to numbers I am referring to the numbers they used.

In part 5 they said that 
$$m(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}(A_{i}\cap I))=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}m(A_{i}\cap I)$$

This is only true if the $A_{i}\cap I$ are disjoint? Which they are not necessarily so. Also at the start they wrote $A_{i} \in A$, shouldn't it be in $S$. (It is my understanding that they are trying to show that $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra).

Also on a more fundamental level, what good does showing $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra do? In part (7) they use the fact that $m(A\cap I)=n(A\cap I)$ but isn't this only true for elements in $S$? To me it seems that this shows $m(A)=n(A)$ for all elements in $S$ which is not necessarily all elements in $\mathcal{B}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: *I think his proof is wrong*.

---

First, he says:

> We need to prove that S is in the Borel σ-algebra

But this makes no sense, because $S \subset \mathcal{B}$ by definition. I think he wants to show that $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. But then, its unclear why he proves (2),(3),(4),(5),(6) because (2),(4) and (5) would be sufficent.

Further, you found a mistake in (5), it only works when the sets are disjoint.

One way how one could repair his proof would be to show that $S$ is a Dynkin system, i.e.

$$ X \in S $$
$$ A \in S \Rightarrow A^C \in S$$
$$ \text{For any sequence of disjoint sets } (A_i)_{i \in\mathbb{N}} \Rightarrow \cup A_i \in S$$

This has been proven in (2),(4) and (5). It remains now to show that $$A,B\in S  \Rightarrow A\cap B \in S$$
and then it follows that $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

**To part (7):** I think he wanted to show that $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, because hr thought it would imply the following

1. $S$ contains all open intervals (thats wrong)
2. $S \subset \mathcal{B}$ by definition (thats correct)
3. since $\mathcal{B}$ is the smalles $\sigma$-algebra which contains all open intervalls, one has $S = \mathcal{B}$ (wrong since 1 is wrong)

Then you would know that $$n(A \cap (-k,k)) = m(A \cap (-k,k))$$ for each Borel-Set $A\in\mathcal{B}$. He is using the monotonic convergence theorem to deduce that
$$n(A) = m(A).$$
He probably came up with that solution, because the OP ask in the comments

> Thank you! Do you mind proving it using the Monotone Class Theorem
>   instead? The text has the theorem in a chapter prior to this problem.
>   Thank you again

However, by his definition of $S$ the fact $$1. \,S \text{contains all open intervals} $$ is certainly not true. So again, you are right, he cannot conclude that $S =\mathcal{B}$ and thus this argument doesn't work.

The only way I can think of to repair this, is by redefining  $S$ to

$$\tilde{S} = \{ A \in \mathcal{B}, \, I \text{open intervall} |n(A\cap I ) = m(A\cap I) \} $$

but that is the same as

$$\tilde{S}  = \{ A \in \mathcal{B} \, | \, n(A ) = m(A) \} .$$

This is exactly what nullUser proposes in his answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1135888/82101 (which also has most upvotes). He proposes to show that $\tilde{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra by showing first that its a Dynkin system. Then it follows that $\tilde{S}  = \mathcal{B}$ and you are done.